# Using an Android list on many class?

Tags: android, arrays

I need to use an array (or something else that you can save many data) to save some variables, but when I save values on the array, I can't use it in other classes. Below is the code.

```
public class addWord extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText wordEdit, defEdit;
    Button confirmButton;
    ListView wordList;
    ArrayList wordArrayList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList defArrayList = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);
        wordEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordAdd);
        defEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.defAdd);
        confirmButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmBtn);
        wordList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.wordListDict);
    }
    public void confirmBtnClicked(View v) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        String newWord = wordEdit.getText().toString();
        String newDef = defEdit.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("word", newWord);
        editor.putString("def", newDef);
        editor.commit();
        wordArrayList.add(newWord);
        defArrayList.add(newDef);
        Toast.makeText(this, "단어가 사전에 생성되었습니다.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your data/arrays in a separate class by using a **[singleton pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm)** and then you can access it from anywhere in the application.

Create a class:

```
public class Singleton {

   ArrayList wordArrayList = new ArrayList();

   //create an object of SingleObject
   private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

   //make the constructor private so that this class cannot be
   //instantiated
   private Singleton(){}

   //Get the only object available
   public static Singleton getInstance(){
      return instance;
   }

   public ArrayList getWordArrayList(){
      return wordArrayList;
   }
}
```

Now to use it in your classes:

```
ArrayList wordArrayList = Singleton.getInstance().getWordArrayList();
// now perform operations on wordArrayList here
```

**Updated:**

```
public class addWord extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText wordEdit, defEdit;
Button confirmButton;
ListView wordList;
ArrayList wordArrayList = Singleton.getInstance().getWordArrayList();
ArrayList defArrayList = new ArrayList();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);
    wordEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordAdd);
    defEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.defAdd);
    confirmButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmBtn);
    wordList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.wordListDict);
}

public void confirmBtnClicked(View v) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    String newWord = wordEdit.getText().toString();
    String newDef = defEdit.getText().toString();
    editor.putString("word", newWord);
    editor.putString("def", newDef);
    editor.commit();
    wordArrayList.add(newWord);
    defArrayList.add(newDef);
    Toast.makeText(this, "단어가 사전에 생성되었습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: It says that the last line is public void but returns wordArrayList

Comment: Please check the answer again

Comment: can you paste it to my code so it matches it perfectly? I don't know where to put the codes.

Comment: but how do you use the defined array in the other classes? I typed in wordArrayList but it does not seem to recognize it though

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the arrays or arraylists as static and access them from anywhere in applicaiton

Ex:

```
public static ArrayList wordArrayList;
```

But I would not suggest using static data until it's not avoidable.

Better pass the data using bundle and access the data when needed

Comment: Also, you should avoid accessing internal fields directly, better use getters and setters.